# Activating Manage site features for modern communication site

Tags: content-query-web-part, modern-pages

I just trying to activate SharePoint Server Publishing in my modern site to be able to use search content query. I found the following message. How to activate  SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure in modern site? Any Idea

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure is a site collection scoped feature.

To activate this feature, you need to go `Site Settings > Site collection features` and activate the feature from here first. After that, you will be able to activate the web scoped SharePoint Server Publishing feature by going to `Site Settings > Manage Site features`.

Secondly, activation of these features is currently possible but is not a supported configuration.

Refer - [Customize Modern sites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites)

Comment: i couldn't find site collection features . I attached there. I do have full permission. Should Communication page different from team site ?

Comment: I am afraid you are not site collection admin. You might be an owner but that doesnt give you rights to activate site collection features. Check [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNus8.png). Please ask the person who created this site, probably they might be able to activate it

Comment: Appreciated Gautam, I do have  sharepoint admin privileges. How to add myself to be a site collection admin using sp management shell?

Comment: you can follow this [link](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/08/sharepoint-online-add-site-collection-administrator-using-powershell.html) to add yourselves as administrator !